# Deploying CircleCI changes to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am pretty new to Git and automated deployments, and I am trying to deploy the changes done as part of my CI to Heroku.

High-level idea:

1. Send my code to GitHub
2. CircleCI picks it up and does some minification
3. CircleCI runs some tests
4. CircleCI deploys my files (including the changes I have done to them) to Heroku

Everything works well, except the files I get on Heroku seem to be the files from Git, not the modified/minified files.

I guess the problem is coming from here in my YAML:

```
... build steps

deploy:
  docker:
    - image: buildpack-deps:trusty
  steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Deploy to Heroku
        command: |
            git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master
```

However, I am not really sure how to change it.

- Is it bad practice to send to Heroku directly the modified files? Should I first commit them to GitHub in special release folder and then send that to Heroku? How?
- Is it just something missing in my YAML?

Complete YAML as a reference:

```
version: 2
jobs:
build:
    docker:
    # https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
    - image: circleci/node:10.10
    - image: circleci/postgres:10.5-alpine-postgis
        environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: myproject
        POSTGRES_DB: myproject

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
    - checkout

    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        - v1-dependencies-

    - run: npm install

    ..........

    - save_cache:
        paths:
            - node_modules
        key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

    - run:
        name: Unit Testing
        command: npm run test_unit

    - run:
        name: Build client files
        command: npm run build

    - run:
        name: API Testing
        command: |
            npm start &
            npm run test_api

deploy:
    docker:
    - image: buildpack-deps:trusty
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Deploy to Heroku
        command: |
            git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master

workflows:
version: 2
build-deploy:
    jobs:
    - build
    - deploy:
        requires:
            - build
        filters:
            branches:
            only: master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CI tool shouldn't be building your application for Heroku. (Of course, it can build it to run tests.)

Heroku will build your application itself. Push your *source files* and let it do its thing. Using the Node.js buildpack you can [Heroku will run your `postinstall` script, if provided](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process), which is a good place to run your build command:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "test": "mocha",
  "postinstall": "npm rum build"
}
```

Running tests against minified files (vs. unminified files) may make you feel more secure, but you're effectively testing the minification tool as well as your own code. Ideally you should be using a tool that's already well-tested and focus your own testing on your own code. (If you still prefer to run against minified code it doesn't do much harm.)

If you want to make sure that the tests run against a bit-for-bit exact copy of the code that you have on Heroku (i.e., build it only once), consider building and deploying your application via a [Docker container](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).

Comment: I added the complete YAML, the target is NodeJS based. By buliding, I meant mostly minifying client javascript and CSS files, which seems to be (IMO), for me, part the CI job, especially since I want to run UI test on the minified files

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a tutorial for setting up a CI/CD with CirclCI, Heroku, Docker, and FastAPI. Although you're not using FastAPI, most of the process is the same.

Feel free to check it out: [production-ready-ci-cd-using-circleci-docker-heroku-fastapi](https://medium.com/profitchimp/production-ready-ci-cd-using-circleci-docker-heroku-fastapi-1a04338cb416)